# Load multiple Django forms in the same page on button click

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to design a single page site where i have a form initially and after entering some data and on clicking a button *(say Submit)* i want it to load 2nd form right below the first one and again entering some data and clicking another button will load the 3rd form below the 2nd form.
I have succeeded in displaying the 2nd form but it immediately disappears after it is shown on the screen. I am not sure how to handle this to keep the 2nd one displayed and from there move to the next form. Below is my codes:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import sampleForm, action

RDS = ''

def get_Nodes(request):
    form = sampleForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            RDS = form.cleaned_data['RDS']
            print(RDS)
    form2 = action(request.POST)
    tmp = {
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', tmp) 

def choice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = action(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            choose = form2.cleaned_data['choose']
            print(choose)
    form2 = action()
    return render(request, 'form2.html', {'form': form2})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit

class sampleForm(forms.Form):
    RDS = forms.CharField(label='RDS IP Address: ')   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'RDS',
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success', onclick="showDiv()")
        )

    class action(forms.Form):
        Choose = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('patchS', 'Patch Sender'),('patchR','Patch Receiver'),('exit','Exit')])
```

form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 20px;">


    <div id="form1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form form.helper %}
    </div>

    <div id="form2" style="display: none;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form2 }}
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function showDiv(){
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

</html>
```

form2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form2 }}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_Nodes),

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solution if in future helps anyone]**

In *forms.py* i was using the *Submit* button and as a result the page was getting refreshed as a result 2nd form was disappearing after every click.

crispy-forms also has *Button*, *Hidden* etc as found in the documentation: 
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html

**[Updated]** *forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Button

class sampleForm(forms.Form):
RDS = forms.CharField(label='RDS IP Address: ')   

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'

    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'RDS',
        Button('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success')
    )

class action(forms.Form):
    Choose = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('patchS', 'Patch Sender'),('patchR','Patch Receiver'),('exit','Exit')])
```

**Replace** *form.html*'s *script* tag with:

```
<script>
    $("#button-id-submit").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
        })
        $("#form2").css('display','block')
    })
</script>
```